# NxBRE Rule engine - trigger on Object changes

Tags: rule-engine, nxbre

I need to do a research on a rule engine for my .NET application and I came across NxBRE.

I have different types of objects in my application, and I want to use NxBRE when objects fields and states are changing.

For example: 
If A.a has changed to x and B.b is y then Do Stuff.

I couldn't find a tutorial or a good example for this, so any help would be appreciated.

In addition - if you have any suggestions for other rule engines that would best suit my needs, I'd love to here it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

NxBRE could offer you:

```
 If A.a is x and B.b is y then Do Stuff.
```

ie it doesn't have the capacity to monitor objects for changes. To do so, you would have to regularly assert the value of `A.a` as a fact in a durable factbase and have a rule that checks if there are more than one `A.a` fact. That rule could then assert an `A.a has changed` fact, which you could use to trigger the `Do Stuff` rule. You would also need to retract the initial value of `A.a`. Feasible but not trivial.

It seems like more than a rules engines, you're after an event-oriented framework? If that is the case, check [NEsper](http://esper.codehaus.org/about/nesper/nesper.html) out.